# Treating Null values and duplicate records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a scenario where I am working on `SQL Server Reporting Services` for creating a tablular report and stuck at a point where I get duplicate values for one column. Below is the sample output from the code:

```
AppID   EmpID   EmpName
2002912 81555   NULL
2002912 81588   Jenn - 81588
2026880 9328    NULL
2026880 9628    Brad  - 09628
2027065 92174   Julie - 92174
2027065 92714   NULL
2028989 72138   NULL
2028989 91366   Alan - 91366
2029233 17438   NULL
2029233 53712   Brad - 53712
2031585 37902   NULL
2031588 17723   Richard - 17723
2031591 54551   Paula - 54551
2031593 52240   Sarah - 52240
2031597 72778   Daisy - 72778
2031603 12659   NULL
```

Notice the first coulmn (`AppID`) has few duplicates and the corresponding column `EmpName` is either `Null` or has some value. I want to eliminate all the duplicate `AppID's` where the `EmpName` is `null`.

This could have been straight forward if there were no null values for unique `AppID`'s (Refer to the last row) also I can't hardcode as I am dealing with large number of data.

Also please note, all these three columns are coming from different table and have been `LEFT JOIN` to `AppID` table. Please let me know if you require to see the code, I didn't paste it here as it is little complex and though might not be required.

Any kind of help and suggestion is appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER OVER (partition by appid ORDER BY EmpName NULLS FIRST)` and select row 2.I`m not sure about the syntax,but this is the general idea.OR use `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN EmpNAme IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` if NULLS FIRST is unavailable.

Comment: I don't want to eliminate the `null` values where the `AppID` is unique. So in that case how will this differenciate between duplicate `AppID's` and Unique `AppID's`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ROW_NUMBER function in a CTE and then pick the first row. Though if there is more than one EmpName which is NOT NULL you will only get the first one in alphabetical order.

```
WITH AppAndEmp AS
(
    SELECT
        AppID
        , EmpID
        , EmpName
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AppId
                       ORDER BY (CASE WHEN EmpName IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC
                                , EmpName) AS EmpOrder

    FROM
        dbo.App
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Emp
            ON  App.AppId = Emp.AppId
)

SELECT
    *

FROM
    AppAndEmp

WHERE
    EmpOrder = 1
```

Comment: Your answer is excellent and it really works. I know we are not suppose to comment for just saying Thank you but I really couldn't stop myself because it saved me a great amount of time to get an answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

@djphatic: Thanks to your comment. I corrected my answer.

```
-- These are those who have set a EmpName but have an invalid row too
select * from data where AppID in (
    select AppID from data group by AppID having count(AppID) > 1
)
and empname is not null
union
-- These are those who MIGHT have set a EmpName or NULL
select * from data where AppID in (
    select AppID from data group by AppID having count(AppID) = 1
)
```

=> [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67cf0/17/0)

---

*For the **sake of the failure** I leave my previous* ***incorrect*** *answer down here:*

You might try this one:

```
select AppID,  min(empid) EmpID, min(EmpName) EmpName 
from data
group by AppID
```

SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67cf0/1/0

> MIN ignores any null values.

Docs for MIN in SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx

Comment: This will give you inconsistent results. Using the example data for AppId 2026880 you would get 9328 for EmpId and Brad - 09628 for EmpName.